# Visual Studio add files to project, copying them

Tags: visual-studio, copy

Right now, when I drag and drop files into the solution explorer, it doesn't copy it to the project's directory, it just adds some sort of link where the "relative path" is something like

```
..\..\..\..\..\whatever
```

Which is quite aggravating. Even "add existing file" does this. What is the preferred method for copying files into a project's directory without manually `explorer`ing there and copying them?